# Can I force an interior designer to stop using photos of my home. We said no photos at the start of the project and i just found them online

Tags: publishing, privacy

interior designer, permission for photos for promotion and or online specifically denied. we like our privacy and said so.
Also, some photos online show that the home was staged with additional decoration while we were not home. complete violation of trust and verbal agreement. I have some comments related in WhatsApp chat saying no photos.

Comment: Do you have documentation (written proof acknowledged by the contractor's signature, or video of you telling the contractor who is present in the video and agrees to your request, etc.)?

Comment: I for one think your description is unclear because there are too many gaps in it. What prompted the designer to focus on your house for promotion? what do you mean by "*and or online*", as alternative to what? why did the designer have access to your home in the first place? or did he? If so, the starting point might be the issue of trespassing.

Comment: @IñakiViggers: It seems pretty clear to me: I understand that the homeowner hired the designer to decorate the home, and permitted them access for that purpose (so trespassing is not an issue).  The designer was either told not to take photos, or else was told not to use any such photos for promotion nor post them publicly online.  They did so anyway.

Comment: @NateEldredge It’s possible the designer’s contract had language allowing the designer to use photos as promotional material.

Comment: Hard to answer by anyone without knowing what country this is in. Something to consider is that if of course you recognize your home, can a visitor on the architect's site relate this to your place? Beware of the [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect).